# How do I upload a key=value format file into a Hive table?

Tags: hive, hql, ddl

I am new to data engineering, so this might be a basic question, appreciate your help here.

I have a file which is in the following format -

```
first_name=A1 last_name=B1 city=Austin state=TX Zip=78703
first_name=A2 last_name=B2 city=Seattle state=WA
```

**Note:  No zip code available for the second row.**

I need to upload this into Hive, in the following format:

```
First_name  Last_name   City       State    Zip
A1          B1          Austin     TX       78703
A2          B2          Seattle    WA       NULL
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Everything you need is [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured a way to do this in Hive.  The idea is to first upload the entire data into a n*1 table (n is the number of rows), and then parsing the key names in the second step using the str_to_map function.

Step 1:  Upload all data into 1 column table.  Input a delimiter which you are sure will not parse your data, and doesn't exist (\002 in this case)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS kv_001;
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE kv_001 (
 col_import string
 )
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\002'
 LOCATION 's3://location/directory/';
```

Step 2:  Using the str_to_map function, extract the keys that are needed

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS required_table;
 CREATE TABLE required_table
 (first_name STRING
, last_name STRING
, city STRING
, state STRING
, zip INT);
 INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE required_table
 SELECT 
 params["first_name"] AS first_name
, params["last_name"] AS last_name
, params["city"] AS city
, params["state"] AS state
, params["zip"] AS zip
 FROM
 (SELECT str_to_map(col_import, '\001', '=') params FROM kv_001) A;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your file using python3 script and then upload it to hive table

**Try this steps:**

Script for example:

```
import sys 

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.split()
    res = []
    for item in line:
        res.append(item.split("=")[1])
        if len(line) == 4:
            res.append("NULL")
        print(",".join(res))
```

If only **zip** field can be empty, it works.
To apply it, use something like

```
cat file | python3 script.py > output.csv
```

Then upload this file to **hdfs** using

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ./output.csv hdfs:///tmp/
```

And create the table in **hive** using

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(first_name STRING, last_name STRING, city STRING, state STRING, zip STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE;
LOAD DATA INPATH '/tmp/output.csv' 
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE my_table;
```